# How to loop in python with multiple conditions

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm currently studying Python basics and got stuck in this While loop:

```
numbers = [1, 3, 6, 9]
n = int(input('Type a number between 0 and 9: '))
while 0 > n > 9:
    n = int(input('Type a number between 0 and 9: '))
if n in numbers:
    print('This number is on the number list!')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGcJ6.png)

What I want is a loop that runs till the user introduces a number between 0 and 9 and them check if it is on the list.
I've already searched for it in the web but I can't find where I'm wrong.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: No `n` can be simultaneously less than 0 and greater than 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should continue while `n < 0` *or* `n > 9`:

```
while n < 0 or n > 9:
    ...
```

The negation of this condition, by de Morgan's laws, is probably what you were aiming for:

```
while not (0 <= n <= 9):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def loop_with_condition():
    numbers = [1, 3, 6, 9]
    while True:
        n = int(input('Type a number between 0 and 9: '))
        if n < 0 or n > 10:
            print('Out of scope!')
            break
        if n in numbers:
            print('This number is on the number list!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop_with_condition()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :)

```
numbers = [1, 3, 6, 9]

class loop_with_condition:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = int(input('Choose a number from 0 to 9: '))
        self.check()
    
    def check(self):
        if self.num not in numbers:
            print(f'Number {self.num} not in numbers')
            self.__init__()
            return
        else:
            print(f'Number {self.num} is in numbers')
```

All you got to do now is call the class `loop_with_condition()`